# Порядок работы при создании сайта. Объясните как по уму делают

Tags: php, html, webpack

Не понимаю как правильно и в каком порядке работать.
Установил и настроил webpack, который обрабатывает scss и js, создает страницы html, да еще и обновляется страница при редактировании файлов. Красота.
На выходе у меня имеется статический сайт, в котором несколько страниц html, файл css и файл js. Ну и картинки и фоны.

И вот дальше мне надо сделать модуль регистрации/авторизации, в теории, пользователь должен добавлять/редактировать данные, то есть подразумевается работа с базой данных и php. Там вроде или куки или сессия(с этим разберусь). но вопрос не в этом.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что на этом этапе я достаю из "dist/bundle" полученное с помощью webpack и переписываю в нем все html на php? ведь там в каждом файле должно быть подключение к БД и все такое или люди продолжают работать с php в вебпак?

Не судите строго, мне не у кого спросить, а видео, где люди с нуля создают и фронтенд и бекенд и потом это объединяют я не нашел

Comment: С другой стороны, мне в любой момент может понадобиться отредактировать файл стилей, не лезут же потом в минифицированный css менять, удобно было бы в scss поменять, там все удобно и понятно

Comment: клиентская часть на js запрашивает через ajax данные c php сервера. Последний отдаёт их в формате json. Это если очень-очень коротко

Comment: то есть, благодаря ajax запросам у меня файлов php  в проекте может и не быть вовсе? А работа с бд все равно будет?

Comment: Не. Ну если вы сервер будете делать на node.js, то вам php совсем не нужен. Ajax - это всего лишь возможность посылать асинхронно запросы на сервер. А уж на чём сервер написан зависит от задачи и программиста